# DateTime formatting 3 letter month

Tags: google-apps-script, datetime-format

The code below returns the date in this format - 21-03-2014.

We need it to return the date in this format - 21-MAR-2014. Three letter text designation. Current time would be nice but not critical. What changes need to be made?

```
function onOpen() {
  var ui = DocumentApp.getUi();
  // Or FormApp or SpreadsheetApp.
  ui.createMenu('Custom Menu')
      .addItem('Insert Date', 'insertDate')
      .addToUi();

}

function insertDate() {
  var cursor = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getCursor();
  if (cursor) {
      // Attempt to insert text at the cursor position. If insertion returns null,
      // then the cursor's containing element doesn't allow text insertions.
      var d = new Date();
      var dd = d.getDate();
      dd = pad(dd, 2)
      var mm = d.getMonth() + 1; //Months are zero based
      mm = pad(mm, 2)
      var yyyy = d.getFullYear();
      var date = dd + "-" + mm + "-" + yyyy;
      var element = cursor.insertText(date);
      if (element) {
        element.setBold(true);
      } else {
        DocumentApp.getUi().alert('Cannot insert text at this cursor location.');
      }
    } else {
      DocumentApp.getUi().alert('Cannot find a cursor in the document.');
  }

}
function pad (str, max) {
  str = str.toString();
  return str.length < max ? pad("0" + str, max) : str;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
    function insertDate() {
      var cursor = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getCursor();
      if (cursor) {
          // Attempt to insert text at the cursor position. If insertion returns null,
          // then the cursor's containing element doesn't allow text insertions.
          var month=["JAN","FEB","MAR","APR","MAY","JUN","JUL","AUG","SEP","OCT","NOV","DEC"];
          var d = new Date();
          var dd = d.getDate();
          dd = pad(dd, 2)
          var mm = d.getMonth();
          mm = pad(mm, 2)
          var yyyy = d.getFullYear();
          var date = dd + "-" + month[mm] + "-" + yyyy;
          var element = cursor.insertText(date);
          if (element) {
            element.setBold(true);
          } else {
            DocumentApp.getUi().alert('Cannot insert text at this cursor location.');
          }
        } else {
          DocumentApp.getUi().alert('Cannot find a cursor in the document.');
      }

    }
```

Comment: The answer above results in the following error when the script is executed. ReferenceError: "pad" is not defined.

Comment: Please mark as answered if it resolved your request.

Comment: +1 for your effort, since OP is a hit-and-run asker. (See [this also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22572712/datetime-error-21-undefined-2014)... they were impatient as well.)

Answer (score 0):

Or:

```
    function onOpen() {
  var ui = DocumentApp.getUi();
  // Or FormApp or SpreadsheetApp.
  ui.createMenu('Date/Time')
      .addItem('Insert Date', 'insertDate')
      .addToUi();

}

function insertDate() {
  var cursor = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getCursor();
  if (cursor) {
      // Attempt to insert text at the cursor position. If insertion returns null,
      // then the cursor's containing element doesn't allow text insertions.
//      var d = new Date();
//      var dd = d.getDate();
//      dd = pad(dd, 2)
//      var mm = d.getMonth() + 1; //Months are zero based
//      mm = pad(mm, 2)
//      var yyyy = d.getFullYear();
//      var date = dd + "-" + mm + "-" + yyyy;

//////////////////SEE THIS ONE LINE BELOW/////////////////////////////////
      var element = cursor.insertText(Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "PST", "MMM MM-dd-yyyy hh:mm a"));
//////////////////SEE THIS ONE LINE ABOVE/////////////////////////////////

      if (element) {
        element.setBold(true);
      } else {
        DocumentApp.getUi().alert('Cannot insert text at this cursor location.');
      }
    } else {
      DocumentApp.getUi().alert('Cannot find a cursor in the document.');
  }

}
//function pad (str, max) {
//  str = str.toString();
//  return str.length < max ? pad("0" + str, max) : str;
//}
```